# Google sheets conditional formatting based on =QUERY result

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditionally format a row in Google Sheets based on the result of a QUERY operation.  I can get the QUERY to return the value I want (either 0 or non-zero), however QUERY insists on returning a header row.

Since the QUERY now takes up 2 rows for every row of data, changing the format of the row based off the QUERY result starts to get weird after just a few rows.

The problem I am ultimately trying to solve in the case where I enter a list of names, and I want to compare each name to a list of "NSF Names".  If a name is entered, and it exists on the NSF list, I would like to flag the entry by highlighting the row red.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Formula, as requested:

```
=query(A:D,"select count(A) where C contains '"&E1&"' and D contains '"&E2&"'")
```

A:D is the data set (A is a numeric ID, B is full name, C and D are first and last names respectively).

E1 and E2 are placeholders for the person's first and last name, but would eventually be replaced with parsing the person's name, as it's inputted on the sheet (TRIM(LEFT(" ", A2) etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can get the QUERY to return the value I want (either 0 or non-zero),
>   however QUERY insists on returning a header row.

There might be better ways to achieve what you want to do, but in answer to this quote:

`=QUERY(A:D,"select count(A) where C contains '"&E1&"' and D contains '"&E2&"' label count(A) ''")`

Answer (score 0):

A query seems a long-winded approach (`=countifs(C1:C7,E$1,D1:D7,E$2)` might be adequate) but the label might be trimmed off it by wrapping the query in:

```
 index(...,2)
```